# Alphabetical bullets

Tags: grammatical-number

When you write a list like this one, are the letters (i.e. the A, B and C) called anything? Are they still bullets even though they’re not ‘bullet-shaped’ like the dot (•) often used for bullet lists?

> A. The dog
>   B. The cat
>   C. The frog

Comment: Not sure there's an accepted term in English. For what it's worth, in Microsodt Word they come under the heading "numbered list", so possibly there isn't a good phrase (or maybe Microsoft just wanted to avoid too many list types).

Comment: Yea, that's what I looked at.  Many thanks

Comment: In LaTeX this would be treated as an enumerated list (with an alphabetic style), and nothing I've seen in any documentation offers a useful term for it. There's no common special term for the numbers in a numbered list either

Comment: I'd call it an illetterated list.

Comment: @HotLicks *Enumerated* is a common word, and *illeterated* seems to be formed in a similar way.  But I've never seen *illeterated*, and I don't see it in dictionaries or a google search. I see one hit on google books where it is used as a synonym of "illiterate." Do you have any evidence that *illetterated* is a word in use?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Are you talking about *list* ***items*** in general (the entire thing), or, specifically, about the orthographic representation *in front* of each list item?